# Get image size from data string

Tags: php, image

I have an image sitting in my database, for which I need the file size in bytes.

How can I get the file size of a data string in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the image actually stored?

Comment: I would suggest calculating the size of the image *before* inserting it into the database and simply accessing that field. I'm sure you're storing some other metadata about that image - name, dates updated, etc...

Comment: Have a look at [filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)

Comment: @AmalMurali It's stored as LONGBLOB.

Comment: why dont u use `strlen `?

Comment: @Harikrishnan - because that would calculate the length of a string and not the filesize of an image within a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT key, LENGTH(blob_column) AS size_in_bytes FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

This will tell you the data size in bytes:

```
SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(blob_content) FROM table WHERE id=1
```